# Keyboard freezes up OS X Sierra

Tags: keyboard, freeze

I have a very weird error that I posted on Apple Support Communities awhile ago that has not been addressed.

For whatever reason whenever I click on/use a menu item (from the top bar of the Mac or the Help->Search option) my keyboard freezes up for awhile.

Right after issuing the command for whatever reason every key press makes the sound like I'm doing an invalid shortcut or something.

After awhile it does return back to normal but I can't tell if it is after a specific time or a response to my key presses.

I have no idea why this is happening. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the standard preliminary troubleshooting steps? Make a new account, test; boot to safe mode, test.

Comment: So if I make a new account the issue does not exist. What do I do now?