# What do I do if I have a crashing error that seems to be specific only to me?

Tags: crash, macos-sierra

For whatever reason I have an application that crashes whenever a core feature is used.

The worst part is this appears to only be happening for me! I have contacted support and put a post up not the forums and I appear to be the only one with this issue and they have no clue why. It has been awhile now and I really have no clue how to proceed as I really need this function to work in the software.

My Mac is a pretty souped up MacBook Pro 15 inch from 2017 so its not a processor failure.

I have tried standard debugging steps such as:

- Closing other softwares (through activity monitor) and opening the software
- Uninstalls and reinstalls
- Testing to see if it has been addressed in the new betas
- Sending crash reports (even emailing them to support)

At this point I really don't know what to do.

In case you are wondering (although it is not too relevant to this question) the software is Affinity Designer and the application crashes whenever I click/try to change the DPI settings on an import, new document, or export.

Comment: Same as my comment on your [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1254207/keyboard-freezes-up-os-x-sierra)... Have you tried the standard preliminary troubleshooting steps? Make a new account, test; boot to safe mode, test.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok so I did try safe mode with no luck however for some reason opening a new account fixed the issue.... I am very confused about why that is? Is there a way to fix this or do I just forever use the software in another account?

Comment: Now comes the hard part - figuring out what runs in your main account that doesn't in the new one. That's what you need to uninstall/fix/update. I don't know of an easy way to do that, I'm afraid, but look at your top menu icons & what's in your Login Items for starters.

Comment: I have tried killing all non essential processes in the activity monitor before with no luck. Could an app still be effecting things while it is not running anything?